# Messenger bot show attachment title

Tags: facebook, bots, messenger

when i'm sending an attachment to the user, he get something like " sent you an attachment", i saw other bot that sending and attachment, but the user get a message with the attachment title if it's an article or so, any ideas how can i do it?

Here's an example code:

```
{
    "attachment": {
    "type": "template",
    "payload": {
        "template_type": "generic",
        "elements": [
           {
          "title": "title",
          "image_url": "image_url",
          "item_url": "article_url",
          "buttons": [
          {
              "type":"element_share" 
          }
          ]
      }
      ]
      }
   }
}
```